# How does PowerPoint choose a Layout

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Assume that I copy slides from a source presentation into a destination presentation, choosing to stick with the destination master/layouts or, alternatively, apply a new theme in the destination presentation. It will most likely be the case that all these differ in terms layouts of their respective master.

How and with which steps does PPT match and assign the corresponding layouts involved? Name? Number of placeholders? ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy/paste or insert a new slide into an existing presentation and choose to keep destination formatting, suppose the slide has a layout named XYZ.  If the destination presentation also has a layout named XYZ it'll assign that layout to the incoming slide.

However, if the same-named layouts are different (different numbers of placeholders, differently named placeholders, different internal placeholder ids, or one of them contains "user drawn" elements), PowerPoint will create a new layout named 1_XYZ. And if it happens again with a different slide, 2_XYZ and so on.

What if layouts are "similar"? How close must they be before PPT sees them as the same and doesn't create new layouts?

"Similar" could mean many things. In order for the incoming slide to be assigned to one of the existing layouts, it has to have the same shapes, same placeholders, all in the same z-order and can't have different numbers of shapes on one vs the other.

What's "z-order"?  It's the order of the shapes on the slide. For example, if you make sure nothing's selected, then press TAB repeatedly, PPT will select each shape in turn, in the order that they were created or that the user imposed by using Send To Back/Send To Front/Send Backward/Send Forward. Shapes that are later in z-order will be selected later using this method; also later shapes will obscure earlier shapes if you overlay one with the other.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean that, given existing and new layout have the same name and the same number of placeholders, ppt will still allocate a new layout, if one of the placeholders has just a slightly different position?

Comment: I don't think it'll add a new layout in that case, but best to test with your own example slides. Note that copy/pasting slides from one presentation to another and choosing to preserve source formatting will create an entirely new (possibly duplicate) master, not just the affected layouts.

Comment: Thank you. I tried building a layout in the destination that is similar to the source layout and it wasn't chosen when pasting the source slide, even though I chose to stick with the destination formatting. Interesting...

Comment: "Similar to" could mean many things. In order for the incoming slide to be assigned to one of the existing layouts, it has to have the same shapes, same placeholders, all in the same z-order and can't have different numbers of shapes on one vs the other.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Last question: What is z-order? Could you edit this little detail into your answer? That would be great!

Comment: @LCsa Good question, good suggestion, and done.